# Is it possible to auto generate ALTER scripts for differences between existing DB and updated schema?

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I built a internal web application for a client that manages applications to programmes for their employees.

The system is Classic ASP on a set of clustered and load balanced Windows 2000 Servers using MS SQL 2000 as their database.

All is fine and I've been asked to do some additions for Phase 2. The additions require changes the tables, some stored procedures and possibly the addition or change of some basic Insert triggers.

Now my question was:

If I make changes to the database is there anyway I can generate a script that will create ALTER statements for them to run against their live databases ? Reason I need this is because I do not have access to the internal live system for security reasons (I am contracted not within their IT department).

I work on my local development database using SQL Server Enterprise manager (2000) which runs within Oracles  Virtual Box running Windows Server 2000 Advance (Version 5).

I will have to provide them with the modified web files and a set of scripts to alter the schema.

I have to assume that they will run the scripts using old software (Minimum circa 2000) but possibly will use newer versions.

Many thanks in advance.
John

Comment: SQL 2000 is officially unsupported by Microsoft. Its time for an upgrade.

Comment: You can build scripts that do this, but the number of edge cases - and the complexity it will require, especially since SQL Server 2000 lacked a lot of the modern DDL commands - will make it a very tedious approach. Why not trial/buy a tool that someone has already spent countless hours writing and worked out all those bugs for you? For example, you can do exactly what you need with [the standard edition of Red-Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/features) within minutes. Also see [this post about re-inventing the wheel](http://bit.ly/19YLhez).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, looks promising and will look into it, anything that saves me time would be excellent. Many thanks.

Comment: Agreed Ken but then I also stated to the client that .NET and SQL 2008 R2 (at the minimum) would be a better choice but they had these servers sitting doing nothing and insisted on using them for the Intranet site.